# Checking table rows as validation MVC Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a table in a Razor view, which contains a first row, as an editor (this is always visible). 
Every row has five fields (description, part number, cost, quantity and a remove button). This is part of an order processing form. 
How can I check BEFORE sending the data to the controller is there at least one table row (technically the second), which contains data? 
The rows id is numbered: orderEditorRow and orderItems{x}

Comment: Add another record to the model you are sending back to your controller called something like atleastOneRow and intercept the form submit in javascript and do the checking there

Comment: Are you using unobtrusive validation and/or jquery validation in general?

Comment: You need javascript/jquery to handle to form `.submit()` or the buttons `.click()` event, count the rows, and it not valid, cancel the submit (and display a message)

Comment: @StephenMuecke: thanks, will try that.